# Is there a way to make something happen only if it is called from a particular thread?

Tags: c#

Okay, this is a pretty weird question, but the situation is this. I've got a communication library I've been working on, and one of its many features is a background thread that accepts all incoming packets from a socket and doles them out as needed. In the simplest form, you can have either a request or a response to a request. Multiple threads can send on the same socket using this library by sending a request, and then waiting for a signal (event) from the background thread when its response has arrived.

You define a delegate associated with the background thread to handle what happens with incoming requests. The short of it is, you can try to send a request from this delegate. Since this is all on the same thread as the background receiving thread, it becomes deadlocked (the thread will block, waiting for its response, which will never happen). These are situations I and most people know to avoid, but I would love to have a way to throw an exception, or maybe have a compile time check that prevents the programmer from trying to call a certain method, the one which sends a request, from the thread that handles receiving.

Comment: It seems that each response handler will block all the requests to your background thread? Why not just handle response in a separate thread? Just curious...

Comment: @6opuc Because it's a library and I wanted the option of doing it all on the same thread. Cases like servers that only respond to requests but never make any of their own don't need to have a second thread as it would just be a waste of resources. The idea is supposed to be that the programmer should have a separate thread handling all requests, but if I or someone else using the library accidentally tries to send their own request as part of a response, I'd rather an exception than a deadlock. It's a case that shoudn't come up though, if the library is used correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can name Your thread

```
Thread.CurrentThread.Name = "Any name you like";
```

Or you can create a static field to hold Your thread Id

```
SomeClass.RequestSenderThreadId = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
```

And then in Your method

```
if(SomeClass.RequestSenderThreadId == Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId)
{
    throw new OperationException("You cant use this method in this thread");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.managedthreadid.aspx) to identify the thread that is currently executing and take  decisions by comparing against your target thread's ID.